# Is any subgroup normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

> Let $\varphi:G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism. Is $\varphi(G)$ a normal subgroup of $G'$?

I dont know how to prove that the statement is false.

Without lose of generality suppose that $G$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and $\varphi$ is the inclusion map, then the problem is reduced to prove that not any subgroup is normal.

Then, **how I can prove that not any subgroup is normal?** I dont know any example or how I can derive this result from the axioms of groups. Can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: You could(should) replace the question with "Is $\phi(G)$ necessarily a normal subgroup of $G'$."

Comment: You should also try to come up with rules for addition that would make a group have noncommutative elements. Then you could start coming up with counter examples on your own.

Comment: @Corey I changed the title to something that I think is the real question.

Comment: The yellowed portion of the post was the problem from your book? That doesn't seem to fit with the title of your post..

Comment: @Corey, I changed the wording to be more clear.

Comment: It is uncommon in mathematics to reserve an adjective for a property that always holds; you can therefore safely assume that if a notion of "normal" subgroup is defined, not all subgroups are normal. You could therefore have asked "please show me an example of a subgroup that is not a normal subgroup". But if your book/course defines normal subgroups, they ought to give examples both of subgroups that are normal and of subgroups that are not, in which case you could have spared asking the question by looking that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is wrong in general. For instance, let $G=\langle (1 \; 2)\rangle$, which is a non-normal subgroup of $G'=S_3$
(let $g=(1 \; 3) \in G'$, and show that $g^{-1}(1 \; 2)g \not \in G$),
and just take $\phi : G \to G'$ the inclusion.

However, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and if $\phi : G \to G'$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then $\phi(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$.

Answer (score 3):

For (counter) example:

$$G=\{\,(1),\,(12)\,\}\;,\;\;G'=S_3\;,\;\;\phi:G\to G'\;,\;\;\phi(12)=(12)\;,\;\;\phi(12)=(1)$$

In fact, you can choose **any** group $\;G'\;$ which has at least one non-normal subgroup $\;G\;$ , and then take the inclusion homomorphism $\;G\to G'\;$ and you get a counter example.

Comment: What mean $S_3$? Sorry, Im starting with group theory.

Comment: The group of permutation on three letters

Answer (score 2):

Here is an infinite example. You can check that $2\times2$ matrices of non-zero determinant with complex entries  form a group for matrix multiplication. Denote this by $G'$.  Now consider the complex numbers of modulus 1 which is  a group for multiplication of numbers. Denote this by $G$.

Now define $\phi\colon G\to G'$ by $\displaystyle  \phi(z) = {z\quad 0\choose 0\quad \bar z}$. You can check that $\phi(G)$ is not a normal subgroup. [Use the matrix ${1\quad1\choose 0\quad1}$.]

Answer (score 1):

It is known  the alternating group $A_n$ is simple, i.e. has no normal subgroup except the trivial ones, for all $n\ge 5$.

Comment: Maybe not the best answer for somebody who has apparently never seen a non-normal subgroup.

Comment: Maybe. I admit it has the unique advantage of brevity.

Comment: This is one of the most confusing answers you could have given.